# ArrayList updating item's attributes automatically

Tags: java, android

Below is the code snippet of my implementation of onTouchListener(...)

```
private Box mCurrentBox;
private List<Box> mBoxen = new ArrayList<>();


 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        PointF current = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
        String action = "";

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                action = "ACTION_DOWN";
                mCurrentBox = new Box(current);
                mBoxen.add(mCurrentBox);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                action = "ACTION_MOVE";
                if(mCurrentBox!=null) {
                    mCurrentBox.setCurrent(current);
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                action = "ACTION_UP";
                mCurrentBox = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                action = "ACTION_CANCEL";
                mCurrentBox = null;
                break;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, action + " at x=" +current.x+", y="+current.y);
        Log.i(TAG, mCurrentBox.toString());
        Log.i(TAG, mBoxen.get(mBoxen.size()-1).toString());
        return true;
    }
```

There are 3 log statements at the end. All of these are showing the same value, but why?

I've initialized a new *mCurrentBox* and immediately added that to the ArrayList *mBoxen*. I am not updating the *mBoxen* after **mCurrentBox.setCurrent(current)**, but still the *current* attribute of item in the *mBoxen* is updating itself (as last 2 log statements are showing same value for all touch events). What is the reason of this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an object to an ArrayList, we pass a pointer to the object we want to add.

This does not copy the object being stored. There is just one object, and we have stored a
pointer to it in the ArrayList. Indeed, copying objects is very rare in Java. Usually, we
have a few objects, and we copy pointers to those objects around.

So basically ArrayList stores refenences to objects passed to it.

In your case you have stored mCurrentBox to ArrayList. So item stored in ArrayList will point to the object mCurrentBox and you will always get same value for mCurrentBox and item from ArrayList.

For reference: https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs108/cs108.1082/106a-java-handouts/HO49ArrayList.pdf

Comment: Then why the case is not same with the 'String' object?

Comment: Have you checked by creating String object and then adding it to ArrayList and then changing that object?

Comment: Ohh, I forgot that Strings are immutable. They are always stored at a new location by Java if we try to make changes to a String variable. Thanks for your answer :)